# I can't see the volume "Macintosh HD" in Recovery mode for Catalina

Tags: hard-drive, partition, recovery

I have a MacBook Pro with an external monitor, and I am trying to force that monitor into RGB mode by following these instructions: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250732856. The instructions say to generate a `DisplayProductID` file, boot into recovery mode, and move that file to the relevant `/Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/System/Library/Displays/Contents/Resources/Overrides/DisplayVendorID-*` folder.

However, when I boot into recovery mode, I only see `/Volumes/macOS Base System`; I don't see `/Volumes/Macintosh HD` as expected. What do I need to do to access `Macintosh HD` during recovery mode?

Side note: if there is a simpler way of enabling RGB mode on an external monitor, I would love to hear about it.

Comment: See if you can get into  menu>About this Mac from Recovery & see what OS it thinks it's running. Your issue has nothing to do with your attempt to change the display ID, it's entirely that you can't see the regular boot drive from Recovery.

Comment: Can you, in recovery mode, open a terminal: Menu at the top of the screen / Utilities / Terminal then type the command:
```diskutil list internal```
Then you press cmd + n which will open a new terminal window in which you will launch safari:
```/Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari```
Then you connect to the forum and you paste the results of the previous command (diskutil list internal) to your initial question.

Comment: @Jean_JD: Why do you need to open a new terminal window? Could you not just enter the command `/Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari &` in the first terminal window?

Comment: @David Because this command sends the terminal garbage information and opening a new terminal does not break any problems.